# On 'update resources' action

Tags: intellij-idea

Annoying behavior in idea 13, not in 11 version.

A have project with javascript and java files.
When i change JS files the only chance to see changes in browser is to "update resources" (ctrl + f10).

If i do it in idea 11 - it's OK, only JS files updates.

If i do it in idea 13 - it's not OK - with JS files updates (recompile) some java files which i'am not change. So the time of "resource update" increases in 3 times.

Is it normal behavior and how can i update only JS files without java compilation?

I ask this [question](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/453312) at jetBrains developer community but have no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug fixed in 13.1.2 idea version.